# Rails can't navigate through models with active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I don't understand why I can't navigate through my models with activerecord.

I have a User model that has_one profile (actually, the details of a user)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy 
end
```

A model Profile that belongs_to User and City

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :city
end
```

And a model City that has_many Profiles

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :profiles  
end
```

In my user_controller, I can access the profile like this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
logger.info(@user.profile.inspect)
```

But I can't go deeper like this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
logger.info(@user.profile.city.inspect)
```

Returns

```
undefined method `city' for nil:NilClass
```

What I want to get is the name of the City from the city_id stored in the Profile model.
Does someone can explain to me what I do wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What is the result of `@user.profile.inspect` ? I think it is `nil`.

Comment: Can you confirm that @user has a profile? The relationships all look good, but if the user doesn't actually have a profile in the database then you will get the above error.

Comment: The city_id field of Profile was null... anyway, I still have an error: `undefined method `city' for #<Profile:0x00000003ef3870>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you don't have `Profile` for that `User` (i.e.) `@user.profile` is `nil`. So you need to first create `profile` for `user` and do `@user.profile.city`. It will work. If you think `profile` may be `nil` for some record still you want to get `city` for records which have `profile` then you can use `try`.

```
    @user.profile.try(:city)
```

Comment: Thanks codeit. The profile exists, but the field city_id was null. I filled it and now I have another error: `undefined method 'city' for #<Profile:0x00000003ef3870>` Do you know what it could be?

Comment: You have `belongs_to :city` in `Profile` model. And `city_id` in `profiles` table, right?

Comment: Thanks @codeit! With a `belongs_to :city` it works. Actually I was using a polymorphic association in my `Profile` model such as `belongs_to :profiler, :polymorphic => true`, but I didn't know that I needed to set specifics fields in `profiles` table to make it works. I did it because my `Profile` model belongs_to :city, :job, :shape and many more. So I wanted to declare only one polymorphic association in `Profile` and `has_many :profiles, :as => :profiler` in parents models. But, could you explain what `t.integer :profiler_id` and `t.string  :profiler_type` stores in `profiles` table? Thanks

Comment: `profiler_id` will store the Id of record in which you are using `profile` as `profiler` and `profiler_type` stores class name.